# How to run ntfsfix automatically when a disk with corrupted partition is plugged in?

Tags: linux, ntfs

I'm wondering if it's possible to detect a corrupted partition automatically and run `ntfsfix` on that partition to fix it when a disk is plugged in similar to Windows asking to run `chkdsk`. But I haven't found anything useful.